# Zero subtotal for custom discount giving error, during order place

Tags: magento2, orders, discount, zero-subtotal

When I place an order it is showing the following error:

```
{message: "The requested Payment Method is not available.",…}
message
:
"The requested Payment Method is not available."
trace
:
"#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement.php(122): Magento\Quote\Model\PaymentMethodManagement->set(19, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment))↵#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformation(19, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))↵#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...', Array)↵#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(19, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))↵#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\generated\code\Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, Array)↵#5 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement.php(81): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->savePaymentInformation(19, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))↵#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(19, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))↵#7 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...', Array)↵#8 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(19, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))↵#9 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\generated\code\Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, Array)↵#10 [internal function]: Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(19, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))↵#11 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(330): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)↵#12 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(239): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()↵#13 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))↵#14 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)↵#15 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))↵#16 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\generated\code\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)↵#17 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))↵#18 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()↵#19 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()↵#20 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage225\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))↵#21 {main}"
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You have place order using which payment method?

Comment: cash on delivery

Comment: If subtotal is zero then Magento will use not payment required which is magento's default payment method.

Answer (score 1):

Error is due to payment table is not getting update. It is solved by updating the payment table.

Comment: How to update that?